# Google app engine DNS issues: Server not found

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I've got an app that I want to run on my www subdomain.  It's been running on a test subdomain - gae - for a while, and is still running there.  In my google apps account, I added the www subdomain for the app angine application, and have added the appropriate CNAME to my DNS.  For some reason, while I can still see the app on my gae subdomain, I get the browser's "Can't find the server" error message when trying to connect to the www subdomain.  Any great ideas why?

What's even weirder, is that I can't view the app on its appspot URL: [saturdayplace-static-sites.appspot.com](http://saturdayplace-static-sites.appspot.com)

[gae.saturdayplace.com](http://gae.saturdayplace.com) - works
[www.saturdayplace.com](http://www.saturdayplace.com) - can't even get a 404 here.  The server is MIA, same as the appspot URL above.  What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being a DNS issue, which I think I've gotten straightened out.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is serving 404 responses on both of those domains. As to why it's doing that, it's impossible to say without seeing your code - perhaps you have some middleware that discriminates based on domain?